# Какой синтаксис инициализации переменных используется в продакшене для новых проектов и почему?

Tags: c++, code-style

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.

Comment: Смотря в чьем продакшене. У нас за этим не следят.

Comment: Только синтаксис direct list initialization, так как он позволяет (чаще) предотвращать нежелательные неявные преобразования с потерей данных.

Comment: Я только начал изучать с++, поэтому продакшен - любой. Просто хочу знать к какому синтаксису привыкать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228443/6944845

Answer (score 3):

Есть два лагеря, примерно вот такие:

1. ```cpp
   int i = 42; // Реже `int i(42);`.
   MyClass c(params);
   std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3};
   ```
2. ```cpp
   int i{42};
   MyClass c{params};
   std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
   ```

Первый - традиционный способ.

Второй когда-то считался многообещающим и новомодным (во времена C++11) - он запрещает неявные преобразования, и казалось бы запись одинаковая во всех случаях!

Но обнаружилось, что некоторые виды классов ведут себя с ним очень странно. Например, стандартные контейнеры - `std::vector<int> v{3}` - это вектор из одного числа `3`, а `std::vector<std::string> v{3}` - три пустые строки. Можно было бы переписать контейнеры, чтобы так не происходило, но сейчас этого никто делать не будет.

Толку от запрета неявных преобразований не очень много (ведь если это так нужно, можно просто включить соответствующие предупреждения компилятора - и они работать будут везде, а не только при инициализации).

Поэтому я бы по умолчанию придерживался (1). Если интересно, можете почитать доводы сторонников (2), возможно вас переманят на темную сторону силы.

---

Есть гораздо менее спорные вопросы - например, стоит всегда инициализировать все переменные (кроме классов, которые сами выставляют себе значение по умолчанию - т.е. почти всех стандартных). Особенно поля класса - прямо в теле класса, чтобы не забыть.

---

Есть еще всякие маргинальные веяния, например

```
auto x = 42;
auto c = MyClass(params);
auto vec = std::vector<int>{1,2,3};
```

Или вообще

```
auto x = int{42};
auto c = MyClass{params};
auto vec = std::vector<int>{1,2,3};
```

Comment: [люди из первого лагеря](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe1jj.jpg)

Comment: @user7860670 [Ага, а вот из второго.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJh1h.jpg) :Р А если серьезно, какие плюсы есть у второго? Честно не понимаю. Запрет неявных преобразований? (А ворнинги не справляются с этим лучше?) Единообразие синтаксиса?

Comment: Во-первых второй всегда работает. Во-вторых с запретом неявных преобразований варнинги не справляются. Надеяться на то, что все потом будут прилежно включать дополнительные опции компилятора (о существовании которых многие, особенно начинающие, даже не в курсе), читать варнинги и исправлять - последнее дело. Пример с конструктором `std::vector` - некорректный. Синтаксис работает, конструктор вызывается. А то, что неожиданно вызываются разные перегрузки - так это проблема дизайна класса, а не синтаксиса вызова.

Comment: Причем подобное может вылезти и в случае использования первого синтаксиса https://godbolt.org/z/9q71sbbvn Единообразие - это на самом деле очень сильное преимущество, так как оно избавляет от необходимости постоянно заниматься утомляющей ментальной гимнастикой в первом случае, вспоминая на каждой строчке про заковырки из каждого нового способа инициализации. Причем заниматься ей никто не заставляет, однако в противном случае возникает риск сесть в лужу на ровном месте. "Зачем рисковать, когда можно без труда избежать риска."

Comment: Под "ментальной гимнастикой" я подразумеваю необходимость при чтении/написании кода в первом случае при каждой инициализации задавать и отвечать на пачку вопросов вида: А включил ли я в опциях компилятора предупрежедения о неявном преобразовании? А не происходит ли тут неявное преобразование? А может быть оно тут допустимо? А допустим ли такой синтаксис для иницилизации внутри класса? А имеет ли тип конструктор по умолчанию? А не является ли конструктор, который я хочу вызвать явным? А нет ли тут most vexing parse? и т.п.

Comment: @user7860670 1. *"второй всегда работает"* Ну да, а как заменить `std::vector<std::size_t> v(42);` фигурными скобками? По этой причине через них нельзя реализовывать `emplace_back()`, чтобы не потерять в универсальности.

2. *"Надеяться на то, что все потом будут прилежно ..."* С тем же успехом они могут забить и использовать другой синтаксис инициализации. Единственная защита от этого - CI в пулреквестах, который не пропускает их при несоблюдении кодстайла и/или наличии ворнингов. CI одинаково хорошо справляется и с тем, и с другим, так что не вижу разницы.

Comment: 3. *"`std::vector` ... проблема дизайна класса"* Никто ж не спорит, но от багов этот аргумент вас не спасет. Если у вас в проекте забанены стандартные контейнеры, и вместо них используются такие, где это работает нормально - тогда ок.

Comment: 4. "ментальной гимнастикой" Хмм. Мысль понимаю. В первом случае мы имеем список относительно простых правил (если скобки пустые - всегда `{}` (прощай vexing parse), если нужно вызывать конструктор от `initializer_list` или перед тобой агрегат - `={}`, иначе круглые (а внутри класса `=T(...)`) или `=`), а во втором случае правил меньше, но они сложнее (если перед тобой контейнер, и ты его инициализируешь количеством элементов - круглые, если это шаблонный код и пользовательский тип - круглые, иначе фигурные).

Comment: Вот еще про иницилизацию: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/18/knightmare-of-initialization/

Comment: Второй способ предполагает только одно правило: использовать везде только фигурные скобки. Без исключений. `emplace_back()` в целях универсальности как раз должен быть реализован через фигурные скобки, иначе через него не получается добавлять агрегатные типы.  "а как заменить std::vector<std::size_t> v(42);" - `std::vector<std::size_t> v{}; v.resize(42);` Собственно возможность неожиданно вызывать не тот конструктор от используемого синтаксиса вызова конструктора не особо зависит, я уже приводил пример выше. С классами stl такого рода проблем в реальном коде я не припомню.

Comment: @user7860670 В С++20 агрегаты работают с круглыми скобками.