# Когда использовать C-style касты?

Tags: c++, cast

В C++ есть куча своих кастов (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, ...). Есть ли случаи, когда стоит использовать C-style каст `(type)obj`?

Comment: `type(obj)` - это не  C-style каст, а functional-style каст, но использовать его также нет никакой необходимости.

Comment: @user7860670 поменял вопрос, он именно про C-style касты. А functional-style и так постоянно используются, т.к. это вызовы конструкторов по сути.

Comment: *"А functional-style и так постоянно используются"* - нет, это такой же признак проблемного кода, как и  C-style каст.

Comment: @user7860670 почему нет? `A(x, y)` это же и есть вызов конструктора/functional-style каст?

Comment: Правильно, это вызов конструктора, но использовать этот синтаксис нет необходимости.

Comment: @user7860670 а как вы по-другому вызовете его? Если вы имеете в виду фигурные скобки, то они не всегда работают ведь, например у вектора.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat залогиньтесь

Comment: @user7860670 Я уже тут, и пишу ответ в защиту круглых скобочек. xD Отвечайте сами за себя.

Comment: Си вариант `(type)obj` аналогичен `reinterpret_cast<type>(obj)` ; `type(obj) == Class :: operator Class ( Class const & obj)` ; `dynamic_cast<T>(obj) == ((obj.real type == T) ? (T)obj : nullptr)` ; `static_cast(obj) == переносит указатель на тип родственного класса, а если этот класс вообще без связей, то ошибку`

Comment: @AlexGlebe разве `static_cast` трогает указатели? Или вы говорите только про случай, когда кастуем указатели?

Comment: @AlexGlebe `(type)obj` тоже умеет сдвигать указатель на родителя, и пробует делать это перед тем, как сделать `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала терминология:

- `MyType(x)` - это functional cast. От C-style каста он ничем не отличается<sup>1</sup>, поэтому ниже я и тот и другой буду называть C-style кастом.
- `MyType(x, y, ...)` - это вызов конструктора. Это [не C-style каст](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2).
- `MyType{x}` и `MyType{x, y, ...}` - это не C-style касты.

---

Есть два (с половиной) лагеря. (Относительно разумных лагеря. Вообще везде писать C-style касты неразумно, поэтому не рассматривается.)

**Лагерь 1:** C-style касты пишутся короче, поэтому там, где они безопасны, можно/лучше их и использовать.

Основная претензия к C-style кастам в их работе с указателями и ссылками.

`(MyClass &)ptr` - вот это что? Варианты:

- Каст к родителю (который может сдвигать указатель при множественном наследовании).

  - Вообще каст к непубличному (точнее, недоступному) родителю, который C++-style касты не способны выполнить.
- `reinterpret_cast`.
- Гнусный `const_cast` (возможно в комбинации с `reinterpret_cast`).
- `operator MyClass &` у класса.

(аналогично каст в ссылку, не считая последнего пункта)

Во-первых, на глаз сложно определить, какой из вариантов тут сработал. Во-вторых, вариант может неожиданно поменяться при изменении кода (убрали родителя, и вполне законный каст к родителю стал работать как `reinterpret_cast`).

Еще возможная проблема - хотели сделать `reinterpret_cast`, но ошиблись типом так, что добавился еще и `const_cast`. Или наоборот.

А касты в не-указатель-не-ссылку вполне безобидны:

```
void DrawHealthBar(float percentage); // 0 <= percentage <= 1

int current_health = 80;
int max_health = 100;
DrawHealthBar(current_health / float(max_health));
```

От того, что вы здесь напишете `static_cast<float>(max_health)`, код безопаснее не станет.

Поэтому **лагерь 1 считает, что к не указателям и не ссылкам можно кастовать C-style кастом, а к остальному нужно кастовать C++-кастами**.

Тут возможны уточнения, например `(T *)nullptr` от плюсового каста никак не выигрывает. Можно либо разрешить для краткости, либо запретить для упрощения правил.

**Лагерь 2:** Везде C++-style касты для однообразия.

Не "для безопасности", как иногда говорят, потому что это ничем не безопаснее варианта 1.

Это именно упрощение правил, чтобы не надо было запоминать, когда С-style касты безопасны, а когда нет. Но это происходит за счет удлиннения записи.

---

Безотносительно двух лагерей еще есть `MyClass{x}`, который еще более ограничен, чем C-style cast и `static_cast`. (Например, `int` во `float` не кастует, потому что потеря точности.)

В обоих лагерях некоторые любят по умолчанию использовать его вместо C-style каста и `static_cast`а, если он работает. А можно сразу брать C-style каст или `static_cast`.

В тему: [`MyClass x(...);` против `MyClass x{...};`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1512522/215103).

---

<sup>1</sup> Одно небольшое отличие - functional cast не компилируется для некоторых типов, в записи которых испольуются пробелы или специальные символы. Это просто ограничение синтаксиса, и если вынести тип в typedef/using, то все начинает работать:

```
// int *ptr = int*(x); // Ошибка.
// unsigned int y = unsigned int(x); // Ошибка. Хотя MSVC это компилирует, это нарушает стандарт.
using A = int *;
int *ptr = A(x); // ок
using B = unsigned int;
unsigned int y = B(x); // ок
unsigned int z = unsigned(x); // ок
```

Comment: 1) _Это не C-style каст._ - тут не очень понял; вы привели ссылку на пункт, где описывается как раз functional-style каст: _followed by a parenthesized optional expression-list_, где _expression-list_ не обязан состоять только из 1 элемента; `MyType{x, y, ...}` тоже functional-style каст исходя из этого пункта; 2) Существуют ли ситуации, когда C-style каст неизбежен, т.е. его нельзя заменить C++ кастами?

Comment: @Ivan43 (1) - "If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression" Если там один параметр, то это эквивалентно C-style касту. Если >1, то не эквивалентно. (2) Да, и в ответе это всколзь упоминается. C-style каст умеет кастовать указатель-ссылку к недоступному (т.е. не публичному, если мы снаружи класса) родителю.

Comment: 1) ну так это семантика, а определение/синтаксис каста в первом пункте, т.е. _functional-style каст эквивалентен C-style касту в случае одного аргумента, но functional-style каст не эквивалентен ему в случае большего количества аргументов_ 2) получается, что у второго лагеря есть исключение, стоит явно добавить это в ответ

Comment: @Ivan43 (1) Пардон, неправильно прочитал первый комментарий. Я с одной стороны согласен, но с другой не хочется удлиннять ответ объяснением разницы. Я думаю и так сойдет (формально у меня не написано, что `MyClass{...}` - не functional cast). (2) Это не повод хвататься за C-style каст, это повод исправить код, чтобы такой необходимости не было.

Comment: imho все разговоры о безопасности это разговоры о неграмотности, т.е. юзер просто не понимает задачу, не знает какое именно число (адрес памяти) ему надо поместить в регистр (указатель)

Comment: @avp Ну такое. По этой логике никакие варнинги тоже не нужно включать.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы использовал C-style касты в следующих случаях:

1. когда необходим игнорирующий *access specifiers* каст:

```cpp
struct A {
};

struct B : private A {
}* b;

// auto c = static_cast<A*>(b); // CE
auto c = (A*)b; // OK
```

Это возможно только с помощью С-style каста и используется в реальном коде (см. [P2637](https://wg21.link/p2637/#implementation)).

[[expr.cast]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.cast#4):

> The conversions performed by
>
> — a `const_­cast`,
>
> — a `static_­cast`,
>
> — a `static_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
>
> — a `reinterpret_­cast`, or
>
> — a `reinterpret_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.
> The same semantic restrictions and behaviors apply, **with the
> exception that** in performing a static_­cast in the following
> situations **the conversion is valid even if the base class is
> inaccessible**: ...

2. когда хотим проигнорировать возвращаемое значение функции и не можем/хотим использовать другие решения:

```cpp
// external function without [[maybe_unused]]
bool foo_with_side_effects();

// too verbose
[[maybe_unused]] auto _ = foo_with_side_effects();
static_cast<void>(foo_with_side_effects());

// unspecified and requires a header
#include <tuple>
std::ignore = foo_with_side_effects();

// requires P2169 in C++26
auto _ = foo_with_side_effects();

// good ol' C-style cast
(void)foo_with_side_effects();
```